# Ideas on load testing of web application

Tags: web-applications, stress-testing, webapplicationstresstool

I would like to setup a performance tests started from our build server on a nightly basis.

I have started using OpenSTA to handle test scripts and load generating but OpenSTA can not run load without someone being logged in on the computer. I would rather having it running as a windows service so that the tests will run even if the computer for example has been restarted. Anyone having OpenSTA running as a windows service?

My aim is to run load tests and collect performance counters on our ci built source and have trends to notify us on performance issues early.